# Angular 2 import node module error: Cannot find module

Tags: angular, typescript

I'm trying to use this node module: [aws-api-gateway-client](https://github.com/kndt84/aws-api-gateway-client)

Installation is successful but I cannot use this module because of importing module error.

I don't understand why it works in any projects without angular2 and typescript (I'm using [angular-cli](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli) tool for my starter project).

```
import apigClientFactory from 'aws-api-gateway-client'
```

I also tried with:

```
import * as apigClientFactory from 'aws-api-gateway-client'
```

but It doesn't work, this is the error showed in console:

```
Cannot find module 'aws-api-gateway-client'.
```

Can anyone help me with this problem?

Comment: Did you define it inside your system.config?

Comment: Question is not very clear. Are you facing problem installing the lib? Have you installed the lib using npm install <<lib>>?

Comment: @echonax Can you tell me how to define it in system.config?

Comment: @Divs Installation is successful but I couldn't use it in my project because of error I mentioned in the post.

Comment: @NguyenThanh can you provide it in your question?

Comment: can you plz check if you have the below entry in tsconfig.json? `"moduleResolution": "node"`

Comment: @Divs Yes. It's already there.

Comment: Ok. You can open the <i>module</i>.js file to see what is being exported to confirm if your import <i>module</i> is correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use it as below code

```
var apigClientFactory = require('aws-api-gateway-client');
```

Comment: `Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'aws-api-gateway-client'`

Comment: It worked for me i am using webpack. Did u successfully installed aws-api-gateway-client?

Comment: Yes, It's working fine with webpack but I don't know why it doesn't work with an angular2+typescript project.

Comment: I don't know why your solution suddenly working after many hours I tried googling.

Answer (score 1):

after installing this package through **`npm`**,make sure you grab specific module from **`system.config.js`** for further use as follow,

```
map: {

    'app': './src',
    ....
    ....

    'aws-api-gateway-client': 'node_modules(or npm)/folder Name Which Contains apigClient.js file/apigClient.js ',
    //<---I don't know exact path as I don't use apigCliet in my project 
    //<---but open your node_modules folder and check for apigClient.js path. 

  },
```

Then,

```
 import apigClientFactory from 'aws-api-gateway-client'
```

Comment: Cannot find system.config.js in angular4

Comment: @Yasar Arafath it is there. You can check it in src/app folder.